# Asterisk Mysql в dialpan не выдает результат

Tags: mysql, asterisk, sip, voip

Добрый вечер всем специалистов по звездочке, есть такая очень интересная проблема:

```
exten => _X.,1,Verbose(4,CALL recognation)
same => n(record),agi(speech-recog-sv.agi,sv-SE)
same => n,Verbose(1,Script returned: ${confidence} , ${utterance})
same => n,Set(GLOBAL(FOO)=${utterance})
same => n,NoOp(${FOO})
same => n,MYSQL(${connectMysql})
same => n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} SELECT number FROM recognation WHERE text='${FOO}')
same => n,MYSQL(Fetch fetchid ${resultid} number)
same => n,Noop(number:${number})
```

Ответ такой,**тоесть ничиего**

```
Verbose("SIP/core-00000004", "1,Script returned: 0.87228245 , Hej och välkommen trycket oss med") in new stack
Set("SIP/core-00000004", "GLOBAL(FOO)=Hej och välkommen trycket oss med") in new stack
Setting global variable 'FOO' to 'Hej och välkommen trycket oss med'
NoOp("SIP/core-00000004", "Hej och välkommen trycket oss med") in new stack
MYSQL("SIP/core-00000004", "Connect connid 127.0.0.1 root xxxx xxxx") in new stack
MYSQL("SIP/core-00000004", "Query resultid 1 SELECT number FROM recognation WHERE text='Hej och välkommen trycket oss med'") in new stack
MYSQL("SIP/core-00000004", "Fetch fetchid 2 number") in new stack
NoOp("SIP/core-00000004", "number:") in new stack
```

В базу даных

```
SELECT number FROM recognation WHERE text='Hej och välkommen trycket oss med'
    -> ;
+-------+
| number|
+-------+
| 1     |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Кто столкнулся с такими проблемами? Подскажите где копать!! Заранее благодарю

Comment: Возможно проблемы с кодировкой. Попробуйте выполнить запрос типа "SELECT number FROM recognation WHERE text !='' LIMIT 1" Что-то должно вернуть.

Answer (score 0):

```
MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} query-string)
    Executes standard MySQL query contained in query-string using established
    connection identified by ${connid}. Result of query is stored in ${resultid}.
  MYSQL(Nextresult resultid ${connid}
    If last query returned more than one result set, it stores the next
    result set in ${resultid}. It's useful with stored procedures
  MYSQL(Fetch fetchid ${resultid} var1 var2 ... varN)
    Fetches a single row from a result set contained in ${result_identifier}.
    Assigns returned fields to ${var1} ... ${varn}.  ${fetchid} is set TRUE
    if additional rows exist in result set.
```

Результат будет в переменной ${resultid} а не в ${number}

Comment: Нет, не работает тоже самое

Comment: а SELECT  выдает одно значение или ARRAY ?